Transform a nested XML array of keys and values to a single row in Azure Data Factory
I'm creating a data flow to write XML data to a SQL table for invoice line items. I have XML source data (edited) as follows and after flattening, I have isolated the "data" elements (under pos_record) containing key and value. How do I convert this into a single row for the invoice line, where the column name is the "key" and the column data is the "value"?
<invoice>
<lines>
      <line quantity="0.338" unit="kg">
        <product name="Plums Pizzaz Organic" product_type="product">
          <pos_record>
            <data key="id" value="6133"/>
            <data key="barcode" value="6133"/>
            <data key="name" value="Plums - Black Amber ONLINE, Kg"/>
            <data key="price" value="$19.99"/>
            <data key="retail_uom" value="KG"/>
            <data key="scale" value="true"/>
            <data key="tax" value="0.0"/>
            <data key="d_1_name" value="Certified Organic Fresh Produce"/>
            <data key="d_2_name" value="Fresh Fruit"/>
            <data key="d_1_code" value="Certified Organic Fresh Produce"/>
            <data key="d_2_code" value="Fresh Fruit"/>
            <data key="last_sold" value=""/>
            <data key="brand" value=""/>
          </pos_record>
        </product>
      </line>
</lines>
</invoice>

Expected Output:



id
qty
unit
name
product_type
product_pos_id
product_pos_barcode
etc.




1
0.338
kg
Plums Pizzaz Organic
product
6133
6133
etc.


n
qty
unit
product name
type
pos_id
pos_barcode
etc.



Note that each invoice contains multiple invoice lines and each line may have multiple "data" elements (or none) under pos_record - whilst the "data" elements are known at this point, they may change in future so it needs to do this dynamically.

Be great to see your attempt.

So if you're doing this dynamically... why does line/product@name get transformed to product_name but line/product@product_type gets transformed to product_type instead of product_product_type? Would be great to see the code you have for this so far.

You can use a powershell script to parse the xml and then load into database
using assembly System.Xml.Linq
$xml = @"
<invoice>
<lines>
      <line quantity="0.338" unit="kg">
        <product name="Plums Pizzaz Organic" product_type="product">
          <pos_record>
            <data key="id" value="6133"/>
            <data key="barcode" value="6133"/>
            <data key="name" value="Plums - Black Amber ONLINE, Kg"/>
            <data key="price" value="$19.99"/>
            <data key="retail_uom" value="KG"/>
            <data key="scale" value="true"/>
            <data key="tax" value="0.0"/>
            <data key="d_1_name" value="Certified Organic Fresh Produce"/>
            <data key="d_2_name" value="Fresh Fruit"/>
            <data key="d_1_code" value="Certified Organic Fresh Produce"/>
            <data key="d_2_code" value="Fresh Fruit"/>
            <data key="last_sold" value=""/>
            <data key="brand" value=""/>
          </pos_record>
        </product>
      </line>
</lines>
</invoice>
"@
$doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Parse($xml)

$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
$id = 1
foreach($line in $doc.Descendants('line'))
{
   $newRow = [pscustomobject]@{}
   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName product_id -NotePropertyValue $id
   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName qty -NotePropertyValue $line.Attribute('quantity').Value
   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName unit -NotePropertyValue $line.Attribute('unit').Value
   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName product_name -NotePropertyValue $line.Element('product').Attribute('name').Value
   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName product_type -NotePropertyValue $line.Element('product').Attribute('product_type').Value
   $pos_record = $line.Descendants('pos_record')[0]
   foreach($data in $pos_record.Elements('data'))
   {
      $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $data.Attribute('key').Value -NotePropertyValue $data.Attribute('value').Value
   }
    $table.Add($newRow) | out-null
    $id++
}
$table

